# Find symbol without recognizing CamelHumps

Tags: intellij-idea, camelcasing

Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in IntelliJ Idea allows you Search for symbols in the workspace. I want to search for any class with this name pattern:

`*IT` (ending with the letters IT, e.g. `HappyHippoIT`)

IntelliJ automatically recognizes such uppercase letters as CamelHumps and searches for class with this name pattern, too:

`*I*T*` (e.g. `BeautyfulIconTransferStrategy`)

Guess what, there are plenty of them, which flooding my search results and hiding the class I was looking for.

**TL;DR: How can I temporarily disable CamelHumps recognition?**

Comment: Aren't items with "IT" together at the top of the list?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It starts with classes like ITable

Comment: That's actually "yes" because "ITable" contains "IT". But this indeed could be improved, I've filed https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172282 for that.

Comment: You are right. I thought you mean the *IT files. Those files are sadly somewhere at the end of the list.